# How to find out session name of telegram app?

Tags: telegram, telethon

I have created a telegram app via https://my.telegram.org. After I did that I got data about **api_id** and **api_hash** but I can't find **session name**. Where can I find it?

When I use telethon function TelegramClient, I need to pass there SESSION:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient

client = TelegramClient(SESSION, API_ID, API_HASH)
```

I can't find the session name

Comment: look this one . https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id

Comment: What do you mean by 'session name'? Are you talking about the first parameter passed to `TelegramClient` ?

Comment: @0stone0 yes exactly

Answer (score 2):

> Where can I find it?

You cant, you'll need to *create* it.

---

[Telethon sessions](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/sessions.html) are used to save the data of your current session.

They're not part of the Telegram API, just something [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) introduced.

> The first parameter you pass to the constructor of the `TelegramClient` is the **session**, and defaults to be the session name (or full path). That is, if you create a `TelegramClient('anon')` instance and connect, an `anon.session` file will be created in the working directory.

> The file name of the session file to be used if a string is given (it may be a full path), or the Session instance to be used otherwise. If it’s `None`, the session will not be saved, and you should call `log_out()` when you’re done.

---

You can just pass `None` (to not save a session), or a 'usefull' name like `Anon`:

```py
client = TelegramClient('anon', '19071234', 'e40ef8a46648716835434')
client.start()
```